# Adding span to PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Hey guys I have been working on a PHP table and would like to add some tooltips to my table data. I'm using the hint.css library.

```
$housingvar .= "<table>". "<tbdoy>". "<tr>". "<td>". $result['username']. "</td>".  "</tr>".  "</tbody>". "</table>";
```

Thats my piece of code. I need to add a tooltip to $result['username'] part. Any idea how I would do that? I cannot use echo on my software.

```
<span class="hint--bottom" aria-label="Thank you!">hover over me.</span>
```

Thats how you make tooltips in HINT.CSS

Cheers and regards.

Comment: Wouldn't you just add that code in place of the `$result['username']` part?

Comment: `<span class="hint--bottom" aria-label="<?php echo $result['username']">hover over me.</span>`

Comment: Like I said. I cant use echo. I use the variable $housingvar later in a pure HTML template. So any other method is really appreciated.

Comment: why can't u use echo? how do u expect to display data?

Comment: since you can't immediately output with an `echo` have you tried using an [`output_buffer`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)
?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I'm using the variable $housingvar in my HTML template. It gets all the data from the PHP file and displays. Its MyBB forum software. Using echo won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you "can't use an echo" you should look at using an output buffer which allows you to capture what would be echos to a variable and use it later

```
<?php ob_start();

echo "something, but it does not print now";
echo "echo something else";

$output = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

// now you have a variable set to what would have been output to the screen
// and can use it in your template later
?>
```

[read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)